# Amazon S3 Cloud: How to set right timeout for downloading bigger files

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, timeout

I'm recently working on an iPad (OSX 7) application, where I download contents from an `Amazon S3 Cloud`. However, this works fine but I'm running into some issues with big files. The problem occures if I want to download some video files.

`Amazon S3 Client` has a timeout for `Connection` which is 4 minutes by default. At the moment I just increased the timeout to 20minutes.

```
s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentialsProvider:provider];

// Extended timeout because are working with larger files (default = 480 seconds)
s3.timeout = 1200; //20minutes
```

Just had to download a videofile which was around 55MB and after 20minutes, I downloaded only 42MB, so my application stucks.

**My Question** Do I just have to increase the timeout volume to 2 hours, or am I doing some stupid stuff while downloading big files?! (I mean 21MB within 10 minutes is really poor...)

Here's the download method:

```
MYMamCloudFileRequest* req = [[MYMAMCloudManager sharedManager] generateFileRequest]; //get AmazonS3 Client

[req downloadFileWithName:mo.name withDestination:filePath andSuccessBlock:^(id result){  
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.handler(MYMAMCloundImporter_RESULT_ADDED_OBJECT, status);  // Handler for showing progress

    });        
    weakSelf.currentMamObjectToBeImported++;
    [weakSelf downloadNextCloudObject];

    } andProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesDownloaded, NSInteger totalBytes){

        DLOGcomment(@"Progress: %i / %i", bytesDownloaded, totalBytes); // showing current download progress

    } andErrorBlock:^(MYErrorWrapper* error){
       [error log];

}];   
}

- (void)downloadFileWithName:(NSString*)fileName
                 withDestination:(NSString*)dest
             andSuccessBlock:(MYMamCloudFileRequestSuccessBlock)successBlock andProgressBlock:(MYMamCloudFileRequestProgressBlock)progressBlock andErrorBlock:(MYMamCloudFileRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock {

    [self getFileSize:fileName];

    self.destinationFileName = dest;

    self.successBlock = successBlock;
    self.errorBlock = errorBlock;
    self.progressBlock = progressBlock;

    self.outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:dest append:NO];
    [self.outputStream open];

    S3GetObjectRequest *downloadRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:fileName withBucket:self.bucket];
    [downloadRequest setDelegate:self];
    [downloadRequest setOutputStream:self.outputStream];
    [self.client getObject:downloadRequest];

    [requestQueue addObject:self];

}
```